Is there a way to detect if local players character is touching the hitbox instead of the victim? Luau
Main question for me is can I make it so that it can access the local players character from a variable given in a module script? I can't seem to access the character of it, even though it still IS the local player and prints out local players name.
if we guess that:
module script:
local info = {

localplayer = game.Players.LocalPlayer,

}
return info

how do I access the character? (the script making the hitbox isn't a local script.)

This question is similar to: Roblox Why can't I get Players.LocalPlayer.Character in game. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Player objects in Roblox have a Character property that you can access pretty easily. It can be accessed as such, barring any timing issues:
local info = {
    localplayer = game.Players.LocalPlayer,
    localcharacter = localplayer.Character,
}
return info

